# decomposing a product

Tags: logarithms

Suppose I have the relation:

$$XY = Z$$

I want to find the 'contribution' or share that $X$ and $Y$ makes to $Z$. So I ln both sides:

$$\ln(X) + \ln(Y) = \ln(Z)$$

We could divide by $\ln(Z)$, so I have

$$\frac{\ln(X)}{\ln(Z)} + \frac{\ln(Y)}{\ln(Z)} = 1$$

Is it correct to say $\frac{\ln(X)}{\ln(Z)}$ is somehow the contribution of of $X$ to $Z$?

Comment: You should type equations in [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: To anyone: Should this have the 'soft-question' tag?

Comment: Yes, that seems like a good way of looking at it.